# Unable to launch website using selenium webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I have downloaded the IE server, extracted it and saved it in the I folder in IE folder. I am unable to execute the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "H://IE/IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I am getting the below error:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.46.0.0
Listening on port 4367
Exception in thread "main"
```

> SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching  Internet
>   Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones.
>   Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or
>   disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information)

Comment: Which part of "Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones." are you having problems with? See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set same Security level in all zones. To do that follow the steps below:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security
3. Set all zones to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter.

Comment: Hi, How can I measure the time taken for loading the page in internet explorer?